# How to make Vim autosuggest Lua methods when typing?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, lua, torch

For auto-completion, I have installed the `youcompleteme` and `vim-lua-ftplugin`, but when I try to trigger the auto-completion, I get the error

```
> 处理 function
> xolox#lua#omnifunc..xolox#lua#getomnivariables..xolox#lua#dofile..xolox#misc#os#exec
> 时发生错误:                         行  163:                                
> E605: 异常没有被捕获: vim-misc 1.17.6: External command failed with exit code
> 139!^@Command line: sh -c '('\''lua'\'' '\''/home/meijie
> ru/.vim/bundle/vim-lua-ftplugin/misc/lua-ftplugin/omnicomplete.lua'\''
> '\''argcheck'\'' '\''argcheck.doc'\'' '\''argcheck.dump'\'' '\'
> 'argcheck.env'\'' '\''argcheck.graph'\'' '\''argcheck.init'\''
> '\''argcheck.usage'\'' '\''argcheck.utils'\'' '\''base64'\''
> '\''bit32' \'' '\''cjson'\'' '\''cjson.util'\'' '\''coroutine'\''
> '\''crypto'\'' '\''cwrap'\'' '\''cwrap.cinterface'\''
> '\''cwrap.init'\'' '\''cw rap.types'\'' '\''debug'\'' '\''dok'\''
> '\''dok.init'\'' '\''dok.inline'\'' '\''env'\'' '\''env.init'\''
> '\''fftw3'\'' '\''fftw3.cdefs '\'' '\''fftw3.defines'\''
> '\''fftw3.init'\'' '\''gnuplot'\'' '\''gnuplot.gnuplot'\''
> '\''gnuplot.hist'\'' '\''gnuplot.init'\'' '\''gr aph'\''
> '\''graph.Edge'\'' '\''graph.graphviz'\'' '\''graph.init'\''
> '\''graph.Node'\'' '\''graphicsmagick'\'' '\''graphicsmagick.conv
> ert'\'' '\''graphicsmagick.exif'\'' '\''graphicsmagick.Image'\''
> '\''graphicsmag                                                      
> 请按 ENTER 或其它命令继续                                                      
> 处理 function
> xolox#lua#omnifunc..xolox#lua#getomnivariables..xolox#lua#dofile
> 时发生错误:                                             行   41:            
> E171: 缺少 :endif                                                       
> 请按 ENTER 或其它命令继续                                                      
> 处理 function xolox#lua#omnifunc 时发生错误:                                 
> 行   10:                                                               
> E171: 缺少 :endif
```

I'm mostly working in torch7. I'd really appreciate a way of getting library methods suggested while typing.

Comment: The issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/xolox/vim-lua-ftplugin/issues).

Comment: I have added a issue,but with no responce